# How do i hide an image and make it appear on a timer.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image that is being shown and after a while it fades out... i want the second image to be hidden and when the first image has faded out the second image to fade in.

```
<script>
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('#fadeout').hide(2000);
    }, 4000);

</script>
<style>

    #Motherboard {
        width: 488px;
        height: 430px;
        background-image: url("img/motherboard.png");
    }
    #Motherboard1 {
        width: 488px;
        height: 430px;
        background-image: url("img/motherboard1.png");      
    }
</style>
<body>
<div id="fadeout">
    <div id="Motherboard1"></div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="Motherboard"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

I have the first image fading out i am struggling to hide and then show the second image. in the  with the id #container.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Look into .hide()'s callback.

Comment: Check http://api.jquery.com/hide/ You need to fadeIn the second image on the complete function of the hide on the first image. Basic structure `$('#fadeout').hide(2000, function() { //do something else })` examples are on the jquery doc page, scroll down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them to start fading at the same time then following should do it.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('#fadeout').hide(2000);
        $('#fadein').show(2000);
    }, 4000);
```

If you want first image to finish fading out and only then second should start fading in then

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('#fadeout').hide(2000, function(){
             $('#fadein').show(2000);
        });

    }, 4000);
```

Comment: I want the 2nd image to be hidden originally though first... and then fade in at the same time as the 1st image is fading out.

Comment: use `hide()` before either of these examples above. eg. `$('#fadein').hide(); // rest of code`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#fadeout').hide(2000, function() {
    $('#container').show(2000);
});
```

Assuming you want to show the image after the first has completely faded out. The showing is inside the complete function of the hide meaning, when the hide animation is over, do whatever it is you defined in the complete function.

If you want them to fadeout/in at the same time, then you just do both at the same time

```
$('#fadeout').hide(2000);
$('#container').show(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('#fadeout').fadeOut(2000);
            $('#container').fadeIn(2000);
        }, 4000);

    </script>
    <style>

        #Motherboard {
            width: 488px;
            height: 430px;
            background-image: url("img/motherboard.png");
        }
        #Motherboard1 {
            width: 488px;
            height: 430px;
            background-image: url("img/motherboard1.png");      
        }
    </style>
    <body>
    <div id="fadeout">
        <div id="Motherboard1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="Motherboard"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Try this code.. your script will work